# the characteristic polynomial of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

what does "the characteristic polynomial of a linear transformation" mean?

for example let $l:F(a)\rightarrow F(a)$ is a linear transformation that $l(x)=ax$ what is it's characteristic polynomial?

thanks

Comment: If $a$ is transcendental over $F$, then $F(a)$ is infinite-dimensional over $F$, and there is no definition of the characteristic polynomial.  But if $a$ is algebraic, then the characteristic polynomial of the linear map $x\mapsto ax$ is exactly the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$.

Comment: why it is so that "if $a$ is algebraic, then the characteristic polynomial of the linear map $x↦ax$ is exactly the minimal polynomial of a over $F$"?do u have any proof?

Comment: Once you have gotten the hang of the definitions, you can check: if the minimal polynomial $p$ of $a$ has degree $n$, then consider the transformation $x\mapsto ax$ with respect to the basis $1,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n-1}$.  Then the matrix representation is precisely the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web is full with written material about the characteristic polynomial, I invite you to do your own search.

Given a square matrix $A\in K(n)$ ($K(n)$ is the set of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in the field $K$). An element $\lambda \in K$ is said to be an **eigenvalue** of $A$  if $$\det(A-\lambda \operatorname{I}) = 0.$$

On the other hand, observe that we can define the function $f(\lambda) = \det(A-\lambda \operatorname{I})$, which in fact is a polynomial of degree $n$ (to see this you could try working some examples or proving it by induction) and its roots are exactly the eigenvalues of $A$. This polynomial is the **characteristic polynomial** of the matrix $A$.

Now, if you're given a linear transformation you just need to calculate its associated matrix and follow the definitions.

For example, consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(x,y)=(x+4y,4x+y)$. Then, its associated matrix would be
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and its characterisic polynomial would be
$$
\det \left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix} - \lambda \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right) = \det \begin{pmatrix} 1-\lambda & 4 \\ 4 & 1-\lambda \end{pmatrix} = (1-\lambda)^2 -16 = \lambda^2 -2\lambda -15 = (\lambda - 5)(\lambda +3).
$$

Note: My definition varies from others which prefer to define it as $\det(\lambda \operatorname{I} - A)$ but it's unimportant.